# Does this homebrew incarnum feat work as intended?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, homebrew-review, meldshaping

Does this homebrew feat work as intended, i.e. granting a class the incarnum class level advancing ability of an incarnum prestige class (minus most of the essentia and plus new tiers of chakra binds):

> Shape Innate Incarnum [Incarnum]
>
> Prerequisites: Must have the incarnum subtype.
>
> Benefit: Choose one class you possess then one incarnum class. You shape soulmeld (including essentia capacity and meldshaper level) as the chosen incarnum class as if you had as many level as the chosen class -2. This feat do not grant extra essentia by leveling as the class normally would, just the ability to shape soulmeld. If a prestige class specifically advance the chosen class add it level to the chosen class for determining the effect of this feat.
> You gain 1 point of essentia per three character levels.

Example: An azurin wizard 10 take this feat, he choose his wizard class as part of this feat and then choose the soulborn class as the incarnum class. He can shape souldmeld as a level 8 soulborn, granting him access to the soulborn meldshape list and all chackra a soulborn of 8th level would be able to bind. However he does not receive any extra essentia, thus limiting him to his innate reserve (and the essentia granted by feats).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. This is an extremely overpowered feat, with no direct analogue anywhere in 3.5. It’s hard to imagine anyone *not* taking this feat, or any good reason to do so. With this in play, it becomes optimal for every character ever to be an azurin with this feat. I would strongly caution against it, I would not allow it as a DM myself, and as a player, I would very likely choose to not play in a game that had it as an option, because it would feel much too centralizing and mandatory.
2. The wording is awkward; it doesn’t quite *sound* like a 3.5 feat. This makes it harder to quickly judge whether or not it “works” as intended.

So if you are going to do this, I would recommend (well, what I really would recommend is a prestige class, but taking it being a feat as non-negotiable) stealing more wording from existing feats and prestige classes.

The first thing we notice is that [Incarnum] feats are defined as those in which you can invest essentia. This does not, so it loses that descriptor. Compare it to, e.g., Bonus Essentia or Shape Soulmeld, which are not [Incarnum] feats.

On prerequisites, numerous feats have things like

> **Prerequisites:** Cha 11, dragonblood subtype.

which informs you how your incarnum prerequisite should go:

> **Prerequisites:** incarnum subtype.

On the other hand, *Magic of Incarnum* does not use the incarnum subtype for feat prerequisites at all. Instead, it uses, for example from Psycarnum Crystal,

> **Prerequisites:** Con 13, Psicrystal Affinity*, essentia pool.

And since, according to *Magic of Incarnum* page 169, having an essentia pool automatically means one has the incarnum subtype, the two requirements would be quite similar. The incarnum subtype requirement would also cover certain incarnum-based monsters that don’t have an essentia pool, though, so maybe that’s desirable.

This also reminds us that every incarnum-related feat in the book requires Con 13. Yours should too.

As for the actual wording of the benefit, traditionally lines that have you “choose” something write that above the the prerequisites and benefits, so you should probably do that. As an example of this kind of thing, we have

> #### Practiced Spellcaster
>
> Choose one spellcasting class you possess. Your spells from that class are more powerful.

So we want something similar:

> #### Shape Innate Incarnum
>
> Choose one class you possess. This class also grants meldshaping ability.

I am leaving out choosing the meldshaping class here (*Magic of Incarnum* refers to the classes therein as “meldshaping classes” not “incarnum classes”), because I want to use the wording from *Magic of Incarnum*’s prestige classes.

On which note, for the actual benefit, we look to, for example, soulcaster:

> **Meldshaping:** At each soulcaster level, you increase your meldshaper level, the number of soulmelds you can shape, the number of chakra binds you can create, and your essentia pool as if you had gained a level in a meldshaping class to which you belonged prior to gaining the soulcaster level. You do not, however, gain any other abilities of that class, such as new tiers of chakra binds. If you had more than one meldshaping class before becoming a soulcaster, you must decide to which class to add each level for the purpose of determining your essentia pool, meldshaper level, and the number of soulmelds and chakra binds available.

This does pretty much exactly what you want, except that it advances essentia, and not which chakra tiers you can use. Tweaking this to reference your chosen classes, and swapping the new chakra tiers and essentia progression, we get

> **Benefit:** At each level in the selected class, you increase your meldshaper level, the number of soulmelds you can shape, the number of chakra binds you can create, and new tiers of chakra binds as if you had gained a level in a meldshaping class of your choice (the chosen meldshaping class cannot be the selected class). You do not, however, gain any other abilities of that class, such as increases to your essentia pool.

And then we tack on the separate essentia progression you want:

> The selected class also grants one essentia for every three levels you have in the class.

So all together, we have this:

> #### Shape Innate Incarnum
>
> Choose one class you possess. This class also grants meldshaping ability.
>
> **Prerequisites:** Con 13, incarnum subtype.
>
> **Benefit:** Each level except 1st and 2nd of the selected class grants you increases in meldshaper level, the number of soulmelds you can shape, the number of chakra binds you can create, and new tiers of chakra binds, as if you had gained a level in a meldshaping class of your choice (the chosen meldshaping class cannot be the selected class). You do not, however, gain any other abilities of that class, such as increases to your essentia pool.
>
> The selected class also grants one essentia for every three levels you have in the class.

(I massaged the benefit bit a little to make it clear that this is retroactive, which isn’t a concern for prestige classes.)

So that is the wording I would use, and how I would determine that wording, were I to do something like this. However I must emphasize again that I **would not** do something like this.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in a more balanced way? What I'm trying to do is get a psion/meditant with melding abilities to further enforce the chakra theme I'm going for. Although as a last resort I suppose I could just put levels in soul manifester.

Comment: @Cellheim Shape Soulmeld and Open Chakra are how you do it with feats, soul manifester is the answer if you want more than that.